# MVC Authentication bypass for a controller/action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using MVC with forms authentication and I need authentication bypass for one of my controllers, is it possible to bypass authentication for Controller(s)/Action(s).

I tried adding the below given configurations in the web.config file. But, that's not working for me.

```
<location path="Account">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Can anyone help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post() { ... }
}
```

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api?